# R: Set function as generic for some class

Tags: r, function, oop

I wrote a function that returns an object of class `myClass`. Specific to this class, I have a function `tryMe.myClass()` that I'd like to be generic to `myClass`, such that I only have to call `tryMe(object, x)` instead of `tryMe.myClass(object, x)`, where `tryMe(object, x)` will only work of `object` is of class `myClass`.

Both functions (the constructor and `tryMe.myClass()`) have their own .R-File inside a package I created.

What do I need to modify for this to work?

Much thanks!
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a generic as in line ## below

```
tryMe <- function(object, ...) UseMethod("tryMe") ##
tryMe.myClass <- function(object, x, ...) "ok"

# test
obj <- structure(NA, class = "myClass")
tryMe(obj, 3)
## [1] ok
```

Comment: Okay, and now some extension:

Suppose a different function with the same name `tryMe` also exists for some `otherClass` (say, from another package).

Is it possible that the function call of `tryMe(object, ...)` automatically recognizes the class of the passed `object` such that the corresponding version of the function will be executed?

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is a method `tryMe.otherClass` defined then it should be dispatched properly as well when `tryMe(x)` is called with an `otherClass` object `x`.